# Why does Terminal seem unaware of my python virtual environment? How do I get back in?

Tags: python, bash, jupyter, virtual-environment

After succesfully creating a virtual environment and installing packages, I launch Jupyter:

```
jupyter-notebook --browser=firefox
```

When launching Jupyter this way -- even if I'm not using a venv -- the terminal window becomes unusable because I can no longer see the prompt. Maybe this is due to issues with my bash setup file?

If I launch a new window, and cd back into the project folder where the venv was created, I can't see the environment. The usual parenthetical reference, (my_venv), isn't visible within the prompt, and so commands like *which python* and *pip3 list* return information about the non-virtual environment.

I created my environment using:

```
$ python3 -m venv chekitty
$ source ~/Desktop/chekitty/bin/activate
$ ipython kernel install --user --name=chekitty
```

I'm experienced with Python but a novice with using venv. I only started to experiment because having 4000 versions of python on my machine has made it so supposedly installed packages can't be found. It's driving me nuts.

Not sure it matters, but I'm running High Sierra on an older machine.

Answer (score -1):

There could be a few issues here.

**- Jupyter Terminal Issue:**

When you launch Jupyter Notebook from the terminal, the process runs in the foreground, effectively "taking over" the terminal window until you shut down Jupyter. This is expected behaviour. If you want to continue using the terminal while Jupyter is running, you can start Jupyter in the background:

```
jupyter-notebook --browser=firefox &
```

You can also open a new terminal tab (often `Ctrl+Shift+T` in most Linux-based systems or `Cmd+T` on macOS) or a new terminal window if you need to run other commands.

**- Virtual Environment Indicator:**

If you open a new terminal window or tab, you'll need to activate your virtual environment again to see the (`my_venv`) indicator and to use the specific Python/pip versions from that `venv`.

Navigate to your project directory and activate the virtual environment:

```
cd path/to/your/project
source chekitty/bin/activate
```

After doing this, you should see (chekitty) before your terminal prompt, indicating that the virtual environment is active.

**- Jupyter and Virtual Environments:**

If you want Jupyter Notebook to have access to your virtual environment's Python and libraries, you need to make sure that the Jupyter you're running is installed within that virtual environment. Here's how you can ensure that:

- Activate your virtual environment:

```
source ~/Desktop/chekitty/bin/activate
```

- Install Jupyter inside this virtual environment:

```
pip install jupyter
```

- Run Jupyter from within the virtual environment:

```
jupyter-notebook --browser=firefox
```

This way, Jupyter Notebook will recognise and use Python version and packages from the `chekitty` virtual environment.

**- Multiple Python Versions:**

Using virtual environments (like `venv` or `virtualenv`) is indeed a great practice to manage project-specific dependencies and avoid conflicts between different project requirements. It's a good idea to make it a habit to create a virtual environment for every new project, and you'll find it much easier to manage your Python projects and dependencies.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation, Robert! You hit on a bunch of topics that I need to further review later. When I do, I will figure out how to accept the answer, as I'm new to Asking Qs on SO.